# Argo Workflow - share machine between steps

Tags: argo-workflows

I want to build argo workflow. However, in order to save running time and latency I want to run some steps on the same docker and machine (without the need to output and input the data between each component), How can I implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run multiple steps within the same container image, you'll need to create a custom container image.

If you are okay using multiple containers and just want them to run on the same Pod, you can use a [container set template](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/container-set-template.md).

Container set templates are designed for short-running tasks that don't really justify spinning up a new Pod.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I looked for

Comment: Thanks, but basically using container set still writes to disk, I am looking for option not to run to disk at all between different steps, what do you mean by same container image? I can I make different steps to work on same container and share data in memory?

Comment: @user6001037 you can't currently run multiple Argo Workflows steps within a single container. But if the work is really that tightly-coupled, it might make sense to just run the multiple "steps" (pieces of work) as a custom application within a single container.

Comment: You might also look into Argo Dataflow. It uses HTTP rather than disk to communicate between "steps." Since it's designed for streaming, steps are represented by persistent pods that handle units of work as HTTP requests. It's a streaming rather than a step-wise workflow management tool.